# How do I perform OCR on multiple images in Python at once, and print all that data into an XLSX file?

Tags: python, excel, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have about 35 images with the naming convention rsrc(1).jpg, rsrc(2).jpg,... These images are like virtual business cards, containing the official information of several people.

I need to perform OCR on all of these together and print all this information out in an excel file, sorted into proper columns. Please help me out.

This is the code I am using to perform OCR on a single image:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_path = '*Path*/rsrc (1).jpg'
im = Image.open(file_path)
im.save('ocr (1).png', dpi=(300, 300))

image = cv2.imread('ocr.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold)

with open("Output.txt", "w", 5,"utf-8") as text_file:
    text_file.write(text)
```

This is one of the images that I'm using:
[rsrc (1).jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP8IG.jpg)

Comment: So what is your question exactly? What does work? What does not work? Does adding `print(text)` before the `while open ...`give you the correct result?

Comment: please post what `print(text)` returns when placed under `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold)`.

Comment: @xtlc
This is the output of ```print(text)```

Alec Boere

Y4 - Associate Partner - ILO.
ICEURHOR

LDSGBLONDON

+44 07816066831

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this, but I have not run the code, it is only copy / paste from your code and a loop around it:

```
results = []
file_paths = ['*Path*/rsrc (1).jpg', '*Path*/rsrc (2).jpg', etc...]

def one_scan(file_path):
    im = Image.open(file_path)
    base = os.path.basename(file_path)
    new_file_name = ps.path.splitext(base)[0]+'.png'
    im.save(new_file_name, dpi=(300, 300))

    image = cv2.imread(new_file_name, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    return pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold)


for file_path in file_paths:
    result = one_scan(file_path)
    results.append(result)

with open("Output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    text_file.write("\n".join(map(str, results)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [improving quality techniques](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html), you can use the

- **Rescaling**
- **Erosion**
- **Binarisation**
- **Page Segmentation Modes**

You have already applied the **rescaling** and **binarisation** techniques, but the output should have a blank-white image. Therefore you are not getting the desired result. Generally, the best result obtained using [OTSU](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)'s thresholding. To use OTSU's thresholding you need to load the image, convert it to the gray-scale. Result will be:

[image]

You can make the font a little bit bolder, by applying the [erosion](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html):

[image]

Now if you apply OCR setting page-segmentation-mode to the [6](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) (Assuming the image as a single uniform block of text.):

```
Alec Boere

14 - Associate Partner - ILO

ICEURHOR &
LDSGBLONDON

+44 07816066831
```

You can get the number correctly at least.

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Loaf the image
img = cv2.imread("fP8IG.jpg")

# Up-sample
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

# Convert to the Gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Erode
erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=1)

# Simple-threshold
thr = cv2.threshold(erd, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6")
print(txt)

# Display
cv2.imshow("", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. I'll definitely add this to my code